# Type of JOIN for this SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, join

I am having fun by using SQL on Excel Tables but could no figure out the right query for what I want to do. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction to get the following result?

I have 2 tables that I want to join:

‘Table3’

```
SN  IN DATE
1   10.09.2018
2   27.08.2018
3   19.08.2018
4   20.08.2018
```

The serial number is unique

‘Database’

```
SN  REF CREATION DATE   TIMESTAMP
1   AAA 11.09.2018  26.10.2018
1   AAB 11.09.2018  27.10.2018
2   ACF 11.09.2018  27.10.2018
2   CDR 11.09.2018  27.10.2018
3   ODC 11.09.2018  27.10.2018
4   RTF 11.09.2018  27.10.2018
4   IKG 11.09.2018  27.10.2018
4   RNO 11.09.2018  27.10.2018
```

REF does belong to one SN only

Result I want (in my query, I include more columns to help me crosscheck the result):

```
SN  REF
1   AAB
2   ACF
2   CDR
3   ODC
4   RTF
4   IKG
4   RNO
```

I want all the REF with a TIMESTAMP=TODAY (in my exemple, today is 27.10.2018) and IN DATE < CREATION DATE for each Serial Number (SN) of the ‘Table3’

This is the query I came up so far:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Table3$].[SN],[Table3$].[IN DATE],[Database$].[REF],[Database$].[CREATION DATE],[Database$].[TIMESTAMP] " & _
            "FROM [Table3$] " & _
            "LEFT JOIN [Database$] ON [Table3$].[IN DATE]<[Database$].[CREATION DATE]"
```

I think I need a LEFT JOIN but the result It gives me are not correct. Also, I assume a WHERE to specifiy the ‘today’ value is needed.
I need help to build the right logic there.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view this query would be what you want:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Table3$].[SN], [Table3$].[ IN DATE], [Database$].[NOTIFICATION NUMBER], [Database$].[CREATION DATE], [Database$].[TIMESTAMP] " & _
         "FROM [Table3$] INNER JOIN [Database$] ON [Table3$].[SN] = [Database$].[SN] " & _
         "WHERE [Table3$].[ IN DATE] < [Database$].[CREATION DATE] AND [Database$].[TIMESTAMP] = Date()"
```

I assume that `TIMESTAMP` is a date field, so I used the procedure `Date` to retrieve the current date.

I was not able to test it, but it should set you on the right track, at least.

BTW: I wonder if the blank in front of `IN` is correct here: `[ IN DATE]`. After all, you've used it both times.

Comment: The blank was just a mistake when I renamed the fields to build the example. Else Thanks a lot!!! It works perfectly and I can see my mistake. It kind of make sens that I need to join on a column shared between both table. It seems obvious now.